# How can I use a drop down list to change the reference in a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, reference, formula, worksheet

I have a workbook that has many sheets.  Most of the sheets contain raw data.  One sheet referred to as "Quick Stats" contains a bunch of various tables that take the raw data and give it meaning, such as: how many tests were taken in January; which teacher gave out the most tests; etc.). I'd really like to be able to display the stats for any given period without having to create additional sheets or tables. I'd like to select a period and have all the formulas on my stats sheet display values from the sheet that contains the data for that period.

Is there a way to have a cell (maybe a cell with a drop down list?) whose content becomes the reference point in the formulas?

For instance my sheets are named AY 13-14 (aka. academic year 2013-2014). 
So if I have a formula like below

```
=SUM('AY 13-14'!C:C)
```

how can I make the sheet name of 'AY 13-14'! be the result of the value of a cell and have the formula reference the correct sheet?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula will have to use `INDIRECT` reference based on the value of the cell with the drop down list.

For example: if you have your drop down list in the cell `QuickStats!A1`, then your formula will be

`=SUM(INDIRECT(QuickStats!A1 & "!C:C"))`

(Your drop down list would have to contain names of data sheets, e.g. `AY 13-14` etc)

Comment: This formula results in a #REF! error.  When evaluating the steps it does appear to work except that the result prior to the error is =sum("AY 13-14!C:C") and I believe the quotation marks at that step are causing the error, but I could be wrong.

Comment: My apologies for the earlier confusion.  The problem does not stem from the quotation marks.  The error is being caused by the name of the worksheet.  First the 14-15 is seen by excel as a computation and second it seems to dislike the space between the AY and the 14-15.  Giving the sheet another name that does not include such characters makes it work just fine.  Thanks!